# Migrating existing Postgres database to use South on Heroku.

Tags: django, postgresql, django-south

I'm pretty new to Django and it's deployment on Heroku.

I've got a Postgres database up and running on the app server. My app requirements need me to add a new column to my existing database which has a sizable amount of data in it, which I can't lose.

Looking around, I found a solution described by Mike Ball [here](http://www.mikeball.us/blog/using-south-on-heroku/).
I have the following queries though:

- What exactly is South? (I read the docs but didn't get a clear idea)
- Will it help me save and move my existing data from my current database?
- As a complete newbie, is the above link an easy way to move the data?

Also, in general, if you could hook me up with a good guide for general DBMS concepts, I'd be very grateful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is South? (I read the docs but didn't get a clear idea)

south migrates your database schema as it changes in time.  the schema has to start with a django models.py file.  If you  use 'manage.py syncdb ...' to create your database  then you can probably use south.

Will it help me save and move my existing data from my current database?

As long as you used syncdb to create your database using a models.py file in django, then south can change that database and add the new column.  basically, south records the changes you make to the models.py file in migration files, then you can apply those migration files to your database which update it non-destructively.

As a complete newbie, is the above link an easy way to move the data?

south doesn't move your data.  it allows you to add the new columns to your existing database without destroying the database.  to move your data you will need to backup the data to a file, then copy the file to another machine, then restore the backup.  That's not what south does.